# How to restrict read and write access for a particular branch for one project member. He should have access for another branches of same project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, gitlab-autodevops

How to restrict read and write access for a particular branch for one project member. He should have read and write access for another branches of same project. But for that particular branch commit history should be hidden for him in GitLab.

Particular branch commit history should be hidden for a project member in GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

This is not well supported by Git, or Git repository hosting services like GitHub/GitLab: you gain access to a repository (in full) or you don't.

Generally, you would establish a fork/clone of the repository, which would:

- be private (the collaborator to the original repository would not have any access to the second repository=
- include the "confidential" branch, managed only in that second repository.